# In Python using ctypes for passing pointer to struct pointer to C function

Tags: python, c, pointers, ctypes

In a C library there's:

```
typedef struct A *  B;
int create_b(B* b);
```

and using ctypes I need the Python equivalent to:

```
B b;
create_b(&b)
```

The struct A is implemented in Python as `class A(ctypes.Structure)`.

So, I tried:

```
b = ctypes.POINTER(A)
lib.create_b(ctypes.byref(b))
```

but it's not working.  There are many similar questions, but none I tried helped.

Comment: In what way isn't it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
b = ctypes.POINTER(A)
```

is just setting `b` to refer to the same type `ctypes.POINTER(A)`, where what is really wanted is a variable constructed with that type.  The line is missing the parentheses at the end:

```
b = ctypes.POINTER(A)()
```